# I could't find application icon in Simulator BlackBerry java plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, simulator

I've installed BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse. Create simple Hello World blackberry application. Execute "Run as BlackBerry Application". But in simulator window I couldn't see application running. Could not find corresponding icon in Applications folder.
I tried to add this line in the eclipse.ini file before the vmargs option:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe
```

so the file eclipse.ini in all is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.framework.extensions=net.rim.ejde.preprocessing.hook
-Xms40m
-Xmx512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

but I still Have the problem (I can't find my app icon in the "Downloads menu"),an help pleaze an thanks

Comment: I tried to install the .COD file from the menu of the simulator,and always I have got nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the "BlackBerry" button on the simulator "device", it is located at the left under the device screen. The desktop will be shown.

Look at where the red arrow points on the picture below.

[image: bb9500]

Navigate to "Downloads" folder (on the picture above it is in the red rectangle) and open it.

Your application should be there.